# How to Run afterTextChanged off of the main thread?

Tags: android-studio, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, android-textinputedittext, addtextchangedlistener

## @Entity Creature

I am attempting to update the name property in my database.

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = ["name"])
data class Creature(
    @ColumnInfo(defaultValue = "New Creature") val name: String
)
```

## @Dao CreatureDao

The query which updates the name is here, in the DAO.

```
@Dao
interface CreatureDao {

    [...]

    // update creature name
    @Query("UPDATE Creature SET name=:newName WHERE name=:oldName")
    fun updateCreatureName(oldName: String, newName: String)
}
```

## MyRepository

My view model makes the query via my repository

```
class MyRepository(private val creatureDao: CreatureDao) {

    [...]

    // update creature name
    @Suppress("RedundantSuspendModifier")
    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun updateCreatureName(oldName: String, newName: String) {
        creatureDao.updateCreatureName(oldName, newName)
    }
}
```

## SharedViewModel

This is where my view model makes the call to update the name property

```
class SharedViewModel(
    private val repository: MyRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    [...]

    fun updateCreatureName(oldName: String, newName: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch { repository.updateCreatureName(oldName, newName) }
    }
}
```

## AboutFragment

This view model's updateCreatureName() method is called from AboutFragment when the nameTextInputEditText is changed...

```
class AboutFragment() : Fragment() {

    [...]

        // update creature record when creature name is edited
        binding.nameTextInputEditText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            private lateinit var oldName: String
            private lateinit var newName: String

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
                oldName = s.toString()
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                newName = s.toString()
            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                sharedViewModel.updateCreatureName(oldName, newName)
            }

        })
    }
}
```

## Problem

I receive error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
```

When I try to launch the activity fragment. How can I run

```
override fun afterTextChanged()
```

off of the main thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key was to use

```
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatcher.IO){...}
```

instead of

```
viewModelScope.launch{...}
```

> "When you don't pass a Dispatcher to launch, any coroutines launched
> from viewModelScope run in the main thread."
> [source](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines?gclid=Cj0KCQiA-K2MBhC-ARIsAMtLKRvhxXtMCD1bkxe_X2fxUdWg_POGnSaszFoTVPzZNTJ5s5HCO6lbCe0aAlcXEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [ExecutorService](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors#newSingleThreadExecutor()) and then call the method `submit()` passing a `Runnable`.  Create a single instance in you class or inject a Singleton in case you are using dependency injection.
Maybe the Jetpack framework is providing here some better ideas also.

Comment: Thanks, looks like this is the way to go: Create an instance of ExecutorService at the application level, configure the thread pool and create it on app initialization... the repository can receive work requests from the view model and move the work off the main thread. https://developer.android.com/guide/background/threading

This will take me a while to wrap my head around and implement, but I'll post my process once I've got it!

Comment: Update: I just needed to pass a Dispatcher like so:
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {...}

HOWEVER
Every time I change the string in the edittext in *any way*, the app restarts. So. I'm researching a better way to do this now.

Comment: Even when switching to using a setOnEditorActionListener, the app restarts when the user presses the enter key. :'(